# Passing a list of identifiers into an API parameter in Python

Tags: python, api, rest

I have an API I'd like to query with multiple values for the same parameter. This is an example of my code:

```
import requests

headers = { 
  "apikey": "apikey"}

params = (
   ("gl","US"),
   ("hl","en"),
   ("q", "value") 
)

response = requests.get('url', headers=headers, params=params)
print(response.text)
```

I tried changing "q" in the parameters to a variable, and putting the values for "q" into a list, and then into a tuple.

Example below:

```
import requests

query = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

headers = { 
  "apikey": "apikey"}

params = (
   ("gl","US"),
   ("hl","en"),
   ("q", {value}) 
)

response = requests.get('url', headers=headers, params=params)
print(response.text)
```

I got an error about not being able to iterate over an unhashable object, and then a genericAlias error with the tuple.

Comment: Hi megha! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you share the traceback of the error you are receiving? As a note, in `query` you open with `[` and close with `(`, maybe it is just a typo on the code you write here, but check it in the code you run.

Comment: Short answer: `params` needs to be a dictionary (like `headers`). Either construct it using a dictionary literal, or use `params=dict(params)`.